# Error when download a file from authenticated url using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am very new to SSIS and what I want to achieve is to download an xlsx file from a url (authentication required) and replace old file with the new download.

I am following the tutorial posted here: http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/05/download-source-file-from-website-with.html

Everything works perfectly with the tutorial to download the csv file from the url that doesn't require authentication. But when I tried with my url to download a xlsx file it failed. I believe the credential set up correctly, not sure what seems to be the problem, can someone point it out for me? Thank!

Credential Setting:
[Credential](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd8Cg.jpg)

Error Message:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPYta.jpg)

Script Tast:

```
// C# code
using System;
    using System.Data;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace ST_6799d08685cb4ad78633d035fab12178.csproj
    {
        [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
        public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
        {

            #region VSTA generated code
            enum ScriptResults
            {
                Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
                Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
            };
            #endregion

            public void Main()
            {
                try
                {
                    // Logging start of download
                    bool fireAgain = true;
                    Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Download File", "Start downloading " + Dts.Connections["HTTP Connection Manager"].ConnectionString, string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);

                    // Get your newly added HTTP Connection Manager
                    Object mySSISConnection = Dts.Connections["HTTP Connection Manager"].AcquireConnection(null);

                    // Create a new connection
                    HttpClientConnection myConnection = new HttpClientConnection(mySSISConnection);

                    // Download file and use the Flat File Connectionstring (D:\SourceFiles\Products.csv)
                    // to save the file (and replace the existing file)
                    myConnection.DownloadFile(Dts.Connections["myProductFile"].ConnectionString, true);

                    // Logging end of download
                    Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Download File", "Finished downloading " + Dts.Connections["myProductFile"].ConnectionString, string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);

                    // Quit Script Task succesful
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Logging why download failed
                    Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Download File", "Download failed: " + ex.Message, string.Empty, 0);

                    // Quit Script Task unsuccesful
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd suggest setting credential in C# vs grabbing it from SSIS using WebClient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the whole program you need minus the logging:

```
        System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
        wc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user","password","domain");
        wc.DownloadFile("url", "NetworkLocationAndFileName");
```

Comment: keep in mind that you are likely to have escape characters in Network location so you either need to double backslashes or use @"NetworkName..."

Comment: Thank @KeithL will give it a go when I am back to work